# How to use sound recorder save to file and use directly in preload in same file for p5js

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

I want to combine sound record coding with preload function together as full interaction.

After the recorder work out and save the file as "mySound.wav"

```
recorder.record(soundFile);
    state++;
  }
  else if (state === 1) {
    recorder.stop();
    state++;
  }

  else if (state === 2) {
    soundFile.play(); // play the result!
    save(soundFile, 'mySound.wav');
    state++;
  }
}
```

I want it to be able to work for the preload function in the same sketch.
The issue is preload must have something to preload, so I wonder if it is possible to have the recorder run as the first stage, and preload then can get the save data to run as the second stage.

```
function preload() {
    song = loadSound('assets/mySound.wav');
    }
```

Is that possible? what can I do? is the p5.SceneManager will help with the sound file?

Comment: Why do you need to do this specifically in preload? [What are you trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876)?

Comment: I was inspired by this visual and would like to create an interactive experience where users can input their own voice to generate a similar graphic. This coding has use preload and song.duration() to so it can make the fft.analysis to come up with a circle. I wonder how I can combine this and the recording function in the same p5js. Is that possible? https://editor.p5js.org/tinyturingmachine/sketches/GLOvLhqRC